# Are there upper bounds on the L function $|L(E,s)|$ for $|s|<C$?

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves

Given some absolute constant $C$ (In my case, $C=4$ would suffice) and an elliptic curve $E/\mathbb{Q}$, are there upper bounds on $|L(E,s)|$ that are uniform for $|s|<C$? Using the functional equation we see that $|L(E,s)|\gg N_{E/\mathbb{Q}}$ for at least some points $s$, and so would it be possible to prove some sort of result of the type

$$\sup_{\substack{N_{E/Q}<B \\ |s|<C}}|L(E,s)|\ll B\tag{1}$$

where the implied constant depends at most on $C$?

The reason I ask this question is that I have a family of elliptic curves $E_n$, and using some simple facts about reductions mod $p$ I have that $E_n(\mathbb{F}_p)=E_{\infty}(\mathbb{F}_p)$ for every $p<n$ and some "final" curve $E_{\infty}$. As a consequence,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}L(E_n,s)=L(E_{\infty},s)$$

uniformly on $\Re(s)>3/2$. Now, I would like to construct the power series of $L(E_n,s)$ around, say, $s=7/4$. Because of the convergence of $L(E_n,s)$ to $L(E_{\infty},s)$ in $\Re(s)>\frac{3}{2}$ would locally resemble to $L(E_{\infty},s)$. Moreover, if I had some strong result of the type (1) then I could bound the error and conclude that $L(E_n,1)$ was similar (converges to) to $L(E_{\infty},1)$. Since $E_{\infty}$ has rank 0, we can use Gross-Zagier to conclude that $E_n$ has rank 0 as well (at least for large enough $n$).

This sort of argument by power series feels super powerful, and it makes me really wonder whether or not bounds like (1) exist. If they don't I will try to find some on my own.

Comment: Why not just use the approximate functional equation? (I haven’t bothered thinking about it but maybe you can be more accurate using the Mellin transform integral representation furnished by modularity.)

Comment: I do not know of the general approximate equation for elliptic L functions, though maybe that could work

Comment: I recommend that you read a textbook in analytic number theory if it is not clear to you how to derive bounds for $L(E,s)$ using its functional equation. Without modularity it is hard to say anything about $L(E,s)$ outside the half-plane of absolute convergence of its Dirichlet series.

Comment: @GHfromMO What textbook do you recommend?

Comment: I think Montgomery-Vaughan: Multiplicative Number Theory I is a gentle and thorough introduction. For reference purposes I recommend the monograph Iwaniec-Kowalski: Analytic Number Theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the modularity theorem, apply the maximum modulus principle to $$\Lambda(E,s)=N^{s/2}(2\pi)^{-s}\Gamma(s)L(E,s)$$ which is entire and $\Lambda(E,s)=\pm \Lambda(E,2-s)$ (where $N$ is the conductor).

The Hasse bound gives a bound for $\log L(E,s)$ on $\Re(s)=C+2$, this gives a bound for $\Lambda(E,s)$ on $\Re(s)=C+2$ and $\Re(s)=-C$, and since it is entire and rapidly decreasing as $|\Im(s)|\to \infty$ this gives a bound for $\Lambda(E,s)$ on $\Re(s)\in [-C,2+C]$ depending only on $N$ and $C$.

Given a sequence of elliptic curves $E_j$ with conductor $N_j \to \infty$ then $|L(E_j,-1/2)|\to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an (I believe optimal) implementation of reuns' answer, for posterity.

**Proposition:** For any $\epsilon>0$, we have that $|L(E,s)|\ll_{\epsilon,T_0}N^{1/2+\epsilon}$ within the open set $\frac{1}{2}<\Re(s)<\frac{3}{2}$ and $-T_0<\Im(s)<T_0$. The constant implied by the $\ll$ depends only on $\epsilon$ and $T_0$, and not at all on $E$.

**proof:**

Choosing any $\epsilon>0$, Hasse's bound implies that $|L(E,s)|\ll_{\epsilon}1$ uniformly on $\Re(s)=\frac{3}{2}+\epsilon$. Applying the functional equation, we get that on uniformly $\Re(s)=\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon$

\begin{align*}
|\Gamma(s)L(E,s)|&=\left|\frac{N^{(2-s)/2}(2\pi)^{s-2}\Gamma(s)L(E,2-s)}{N^{s/2}(2\pi)^{-s}}\right|\\
&=\left|N^{1-s}\left(2\pi\right)^{2s-2}L(E,2-s)\right|\\
&\ll_{\epsilon} N^{1/2+\epsilon}
\end{align*}

Thus, applying the maximum modulus principle to the open set $\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon<\Re(s)<\frac{3}{2}+\epsilon$, $-T\leq\Re(s)\leq T$ as $T\to\infty$ we get that $\left|\Gamma(s)L(E,s)\right|\ll_{\epsilon}N^{1/2+\epsilon}$. Here we used the fact that $\Gamma(s)$ decays extremely quickly as $\Im(s)\to\infty$, and the L function $L(E,s)$ does not grow at a sufficiently fast rate to stop $\Gamma(s)L(E,s)$. from going to 0.

Now, truncating to some height $|\Im(s)|<T_0$ we get that $|L(E,s)|\ll_{\epsilon,T_0}N^{1/2+\epsilon}$ and we are done.

Comment: You worked out the convexity bound (for principal automorphic $L$-functions) in a special case.